# Passing selenium object references to a function in python

Tags: python, oop, python-2.7, selenium

Here I have an object in which I instantiate several Selenium WebDrivers to control a series of browsers from Selenium Grid.

```
drivers = {
    0: webdriver.Remote('http://localhost:8080/wd/hub' , webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX.copy()),
    1: webdriver.Remote('http://localhost:8080/wd/hub' , webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX.copy()), 
    2: webdriver.Remote('http://localhost:8080/wd/hub' , webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX.copy()),
    3: webdriver.Remote('http://localhost:8080/wd/hub' , webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX.copy()),
    4: webdriver.Remote('http://localhost:8080/wd/hub' , webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX.copy())
}
```

What I want to then do is pass those drivers by reference to another method. Like so:

```
for driver in drivers:
    self.create_account(driver)
```

However I get the following error from Selenium when I get into the create_accounts method:

```
driver.get("http://google.com")
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'get'
```

I assume this is because I'm not passing the object reference properly, and its somehow transferring as an integer as opposed to an object with methods I can call. Is what I'm attempting to do possible in Python? Is there some other way that I should be doing this, or is what I am attempting to do simply not possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating a dictionary of drivers.  If you are just going to assign each driver to a number, its probably better to create an array of drivers:

```
drivers = [
    webdriver.Remote('http://localhost:8080/wd/hub' , webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX.copy()),
    webdriver.Remote('http://localhost:8080/wd/hub' , webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX.copy()), 
    webdriver.Remote('http://localhost:8080/wd/hub' , webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX.copy()),
    webdriver.Remote('http://localhost:8080/wd/hub' , webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX.copy()),
    webdriver.Remote('http://localhost:8080/wd/hub' , webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX.copy())
]
```

Then you can do:

```
for driver in drivers:
```

and

```
driver[4]
```

However, if you are going to use a dictionary, then you can do

```
for key, driver in drivers.items()
```

if you want both the number and the driver, or

```
for driver in drivers.values()
```

if you just need the driver.

Answer (score 0):

You should be iterating over `drivers.values()` (or `drivers.itervalues()` in Python 2.x):

```
for driver in drivers.values():
```

This will assign `driver` to the `webdriver.Remote` instances inside the dictionary, all of which have a `get` method.  Your current code however is assigning `driver` to the dictionary's integer keys because iterating over a dictionary yields its keys.

Below is a demonstration of what I said above:

```
>>> dct = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}
>>> for i in dct:  # Yields keys
...     i
...
'a'
'b'
'c'
>>> for i in dct.values():  # Yields values
...     i
...
1
2
3
>>>
```